# Firebase function unexpectedly redirecting to accounts.google.com

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple Firebase Function shown below. When accessed via javascript (CORS), the function's pre-flight option's request (part of the CORS standard) returns a 302 redirect to a url beginning with

`https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3D`

and ending with my function's URL. Here is the entire function in question:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as cors from 'cors';

const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.post('*', async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('X-Test', 'OK');
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['__session=ninja']);
  res.send('OK');
});

app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('X-Test', 'OK');
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['__session=ninja']);
  res.send('OK');
});

export const testing = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

As you can see, the function does not contain any redirect logic. If I manually navigate to the redirect link in my browser (the `accounts.google.com` one), it shows some sort of Google Compute Engine security page, asking for access to my Google Account. Recently, all of my functions, previously working, have started replying with this 302 redirect when I access them via javascript. This is preventing all of my functions from working as intended.

I can't be sure, but I *think* it started after I tried publishing a function using the Google Cloud Functions cli (rather than the Firebase Functions cli). It feels like publishing a function using the `gcloud` cli might have triggered a settings change of some kind? I can't find any information on this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: FYI you can't use gcloud to deploy a Cloud Function written with the Firebase SDK.  Only the Firebase CLI can do that.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, the function shown above was deployed using the Firebase CLI (and, after encountering this issue, I re-deployed all of my functions using the Firebase CLI and deleted the function deployed using the `gcloud` cli -- though for the record, the gcloud deployed function seemed to work just fine before I deleted it). Do you know if using both CLI's on a single project results in some sort of account modification?

Comment: You can use both at the same time to deploy different functions.  I doesn't have anything to do with the problem, though.  I'm just stating this as an FYI.

Comment: @DougStevenson gotcha

Comment: @DougStevenson I added a link to a stackblitz example which recreates the issue on the client side.

Comment: it all hints for an absent auth-token... else it would not ask for a login. `gcloud` and `firebase` CLI might use a different (or none at all) service-account ...unless one defines one.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks, that makes sense. But again, the entire function code is included above so it should not be asking for any credentials. It feels like my account had some setting changed which is now adding this new credentials requirement to all CORS requests. I've just tried opening a support request with the firebase team regarding this. I'll update this post if they respond.

Comment: @John when looking a the script, it does not obtain any auth token.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I figured it out! See answer below. I was calling a non-existent function (typo) which apparently results in a 302 redirect. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: In my case it was solved by calling the function using https and not http.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On my goodness, the issue was I had a typo in the functions name! The name of the function was `userAccount-testing` and I was calling `userAccount.testing`. Apparently, when you call a non-existent function you get a 302 redirect in response.

I was copy and pasting the different function names in when trying to diagnose this issue and just so happened to never update the `.` to a `-`. *face palm*

Comment: this explains why it couldn't obtain a token. removed my example, because it appeared useless.

Comment: believe it or not, I had the same problem and waste a day on it, and this question saved me lol.

Comment: Indeed, solved my problem and saved a headache. Such a strange, counterintuitive, undocumented behaviour.